# Trying to access class a members through one of class b functions, what went wrong?

Tags: c++, class, arraylist

In the `append()` function I am trying to access class `User` members through a class `Arraylist` where I have an array of `User` type, any help how can I access them ?

```
class User 
{
    string username;
    string password;

    void login();
    void logout();
    void signup();
    void search();
};

class ArrayList
{
public:
    User* root;
    User* elems;
    int capacity;
    int elemsCnt;
    void expand();
    ArrayList();
    ~ArrayList();
    void append(string, string);
};

void ArrayList::append(string name, string pass)
{
    if (capacity == elemsCnt)
        expand();

    elems[elemsCnt++].username = name;
    elems[elemsCnt++].password = pass;
}
```

Comment: So, what went wrong? Can you post the error message you received? I guess you did not initialize/allocate memory for `elems`?

Comment: For the future, please take the habit of extracting a minimal example first. Your class `ArrayList` is completely irrelevant, for example. That said, don't use raw pointers as arrays, use `std::vector` (or other containers) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Class members are private by default. You need to make them public to access them from the outside:

```
class User 
{
public: // Add this!
    string username;
    string password;

    void login();
    void logout();
    void signup();
    void search();
};
```

Comment: yeah this's what caused the error. thanks for the help :)

Comment: BTW, you have a bug in your `append` method. You increment your index twice when you set `username` and `password`.